# Xamarin Forms Android EnsureCreated of entity framework core no working

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, entity-framework-core

Here is my code:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {           
        private const string databaseName = "Database.db";
        public DbSet<Setting> Setting { get; set; }       
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            String databasePath = "";
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS:
                    SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();
                    databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library", databaseName); ;
                    break;
                case Device.Android:
                    databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), databaseName);                    
                    break;
                case Device.WPF: {
                        databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, databaseName);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Platform not supported");
            }
            if (!File.Exists(databasePath))
            {
                File.Create(databasePath);
            }
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={databasePath}");
        }
    }
public class Setting
    {
        [Key]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

In WPF all runs well.

However, in Android, it always reports "no such table" error even I used `EnsureCreated` before.
[image]

What's wrong with this? How can I solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that you have installed the right nuget package:

[image]

I wrote a demo with your codes and it works well on my side, here is my codes:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ApplicationContext context = new ApplicationContext();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();


        Task.Run (async () => {

            var newPosts = new Setting() { Key = "123", Value = "test" };
            context.Setting.Add(newPosts);


            var result = context.Setting.Where(X => X.Key == "123").FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
        } );


    }
}

public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    private const string databaseName = "Database.db";
    public DbSet<Setting> Setting { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        String databasePath = "";
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                SQLitePCL.Batteries_V2.Init();
                databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "..", "Library", databaseName); ;
                break;
            case Device.Android:
                databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), databaseName);
                break;
            case Device.WPF:
                {
                    databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, databaseName);
                    break;
                }
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Platform not supported");
        }
        if (!File.Exists(databasePath))
        {
            File.Create(databasePath);
        }
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={databasePath}");
    }
}
public class Setting
{
    [Key]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I upload my test project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/EntityFramework) and feel free to ask me any question.

Comment: Thanks for writing a sample for me. I add a try&catch inside the Task.Run and it reports an error:{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Setting.Key'.

Comment: What I tried is just the sample project in your Github but not by creating a brand new one.

Comment: What's more, I have installed all the NuGet packages above with the latest version(Some of them you provided are not the latest version).

Comment: I updated my sample project and please test again. I change the code when adding new data inside Task.Run().

Comment: Thanks a lot. I add a try&catch again and found that the var result returns a null object while it should return the object what has just added. I added a 'context.SaveChanges();' in it and it works without any error now.